# xpath java html element siblings

Tags: java, html, xpath

I'm trying to get the values of some  elements. I am able to get the first one but the "following-sibling"

```
WebElement mainelem = url.findElement(By.tagName("main"));
WebElement piclinks = mainelem.findElement(By.xpath("//a[starts-with(@href, '/p/')]"));

XPATH: //*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/a

usage of my following sibling:
WebElement piclinks = mainelem.findElement(By.xpath("//a[starts-with(@href, '/p/')]/following-sibling::a"));
```

the error I get in Java is:

invalid selector: Unable to locate an element

I've been trying lots of things to solve the problem but it didn't work.

Here is finally the html code:

```
<section data-reactroot="" class="_tlwfg _8f735"><main class="_6ltyr _rnpza" role="main"><article class="_3n7ri"><header class="_1l53n"><h1 class="_totu9"><!-- react-text: 7448 -->#<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 7449 -->funny<!-- /react-text --></h1><span class="_s53mj"><!-- react-text: 7451 --><!-- /react-text --><span class="_bkw5z">101,244,153</span><!-- react-text: 7453 --> posts<!-- /react-text --></span></header><div class="_5kftd"><h2 class="_sai17">Top posts</h2><div class="_nljxa"><div class="_myci9"><div class="_8mlbc _vbtk2 _t5r8b"><a href="/p/BWfHui8FLgi/?tagged=funny"><div class="_22yr2"><div class="_jjzlb"><img alt="lol" class="_icyx7" id="pImage_434" src="https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/c0.50.1080.1080/20065328_164651100746803_6799075315676086272_n.jpg"></div><!-- react-empty: 7463 --><div class="_ovg3g"></div></div></a></div><div class="_8mlbc _vbtk2 _t5r8b"><a href="/p/BWeaZpylSXA/?tagged=funny"><div class="_22yr2"><div class="_jjzlb"><img alt="Supreme×Louis Vuitton
#チェキ
#撮影
#Supreme
#LouisVitton
#トレーナー
#着させて頂きんか
#ゆーたろさん
#thankx
#顔芸モデル
#me
#kaogeimodel
#funny" class="_icyx7" id="pImage_435" src="https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/c135.0.810.810/19955663_1269626093146401_407055753111666688_n.jpg"></div><!-- react-empty: 7472 --><div class="_ovg3g"></div></div></a></div><div class="_8mlbc _vbtk2 _t5r8b"><a href="/p/BWfKUOtnYXR/?tagged=funny"><div class="_22yr2"><div class="_jjzlb"><img alt="Gas helium memang bisa mengubah suara. makanya hisapnya harus sampai habis, biar suaranya lama berubah. Tapi nda begini ji juga..
.
Feat : @iksanbangsawan @fajaranzari .
Location : @crovia
.
MENTION Temanmu yg suka joget-joget.
.
#indovidgram @indovidgram  #IVGComedy #IVGStory 
#dagelan #dagelanvideo #dagelantivi #ngakakkocak #bikinrame  #narsistrans7 #maknews #kamuharustahu #makassarinfo" class="_icyx7" id="pImage_436" src="https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e15/19955138_479168035759394_4757550632582250496_n.jpg"></div><!-- react-empty: 7481 --><div class="_ovg3g"></div></div><div class="_qihym"><div class="_cxj4a"><span class="_btsl3 _soakw coreSpriteVideoIconLarge">Video</span></div></div></a></div></div><div class="_myci9"><div class="_8mlbc _vbtk2 _t5r8b"><a href="/p/BWeCwFBgmim/?tagged=funny"><div class="_22yr2"><div class="_jjzlb"><img alt="The word you're looking for is &quot;shambles.&quot; (Via @freerefills) #spoonfeed" class="_icyx7" id="pImage_437" src="https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/19985795_511230512581070_7725260939766792192_n.jpg"></div><!-- react-empty: 7494 --><div class="_ovg3g"></div></div><div class="_sppa1"><ul class="_m9z3c"><li class="_sjq6j _ajqft"><!-- react-text: 7976 --><!-- /react-text --><span>4,198</span><!-- react-text: 7978 --><!-- /react-text --><span class="_4aw90 _soakw coreSpriteHeartSmall">likes</span><!-- react-text: 7980 --><!-- /react-text --></li><li class="_qq2if"><!-- react-text: 7982 --><!-- /react-text --><span>120</span><!-- react-text: 7984 --><!-- /react-text --><span class="_fuu7c _soakw coreSpriteSpeechBubbleSmall">comments</span><!-- react-text: 7986 --><!-- /react-text --></li></ul></div></a></div><div class="_8mlbc _vbtk2 _t5r8b"><a href="/p/BWfFBGMlv2v/?tagged=funny"><div class="_22yr2"><div class="_jjzlb"><img alt="Ładnie wyszedłem?  Dostane like? ❤️ #zizej #tattoo #like #selfie #me #awesome #poznan #poland #foresttattoo #forearmtattoo #follow #youtube #sexy #gday #epic #vsco #lol #funny #cute" class="_icyx7" id="pImage_438" src="https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/19955019_488052818214189_8337665358542405632_n.jpg"></div><!-- react-empty: 7503 --><div class="_ovg3g"></div></div></a></div><div class="_8mlbc _vbtk2 _t5r8b"><a href="/p/BWfK2w2hF1H/?tagged=funny"><div class="_22yr2"><div class="_jjzlb"><img alt="KARAOKE MİKRAFON
FİYAT:120₺
SİPARİŞ WHATSAPP:0534-336-63-19
KAPIDA ÖDEME/KREDİ KARTI VEYA NAKİT 
2 YIL GARANTİ 
ÇİFT HOPARLÖR 
BLUETOOTH ÖZELLİĞİ
USB FLAŞH GİRİŞ DESTEKLİ
MÜZİK PARÇA DEĞİŞİMİ
BASS AYARI
VOLUME AYARI
ECHO AYARI
TREBLE AYARI
MÜZİK ORKESTRA AYARI
POWER BANK (TELEFON ŞARJ ÖZELLİĞİ) 
RENKLER: SİYAH - GOLD - PEMBE 
#komikcaps #komikvideo #video #ankara #bursa #antalya #gününfotosu #ilginç #ilginçfoto #eğlenceli #bağlama #funny #follow #followme #baglama #instagram #likeme #turkey #imparator #makara #beyazshow #gülmek #vineler #vine #vibes #vines #komikvideolar #kadın #hadise #mizah" class="_icyx7" id="pImage_439" src="https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/c76.0.927.927/19986198_1879501575634377_6354536738727133184_n.jpg"></div><!-- react-empty: 7512 --><div class="_ovg3g"></div></div></a></div></div><div class="_myci9"><div class="_8mlbc _vbtk2 _t5r8b"><a href="/p/BWfFqaxB9Mg/?tagged=funny"><div class="_22yr2"><div class="_jjzlb"><img alt="She's happy when she gets food  #lunch" class="_icyx7" id="pImage_440" src="https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/c0.135.1080.1080/19984998_114386345860502_2029808965793087488_n.jpg"></div><!-- react-empty: 7522 --><div class="_ovg3g"></div></div></a></div><div class="_8mlbc _vbtk2 _t5r8b"><a href="/p/BWfGsAhAScy/?tagged=funny"><div class="_22yr2"><div class="_jjzlb"><img alt="Hep gülelim  #funny #lol #lmao #lmfao #TagsForLikes #hilarious #laugh #laughing #tweegram #fun #friends #photooftheday #friend #wacky #crazy #silly #witty #instahappy #joke #jokes #joking #epic #instagood #instafun #funnypictures #haha #humor" class="_icyx7" id="pImage_441" src="https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/19535321_174518429756674_2290073804858195968_n.jpg"></div><!-- react-empty: 7531 --><div class="_ovg3g"></div></div></a></div><div class="_8mlbc _vbtk2 _t5r8b"><a href="/p/BWfGkmNDfgd/?tagged=funny"><div class="_22yr2"><div class="_jjzlb"><img alt="Follow this beautiful girl - @eattravellaugh
@eattravellaugh
@eattravellaugh
Featured by ❤️
 @_insta_selfie
.
.
.
#selfie #nofilter #webstagram #follow4follow #iphoneonly #instago #pretty #l4l #my #style #family #instacool #life #hair #instafollow #likeforlike #eyes #christmas #20likes #funny #colorful #sun #bored #look #lol #tweegram #all_shots #nice #cool" class="_icyx7" id="pImage_442" src="https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/19955067_207718129756354_5852653957465243648_n.jpg"></div><!-- react-empty: 7540 --><div class="_ovg3g"></div></div></a></div></div></div></div><h2 class="_sai17">Most recent</h2><div><div class="_nljxa"><div class="_myci9"><div class="_8mlbc _vbtk2 _t5r8b"><a href="/p/BWfOmLfgcGl/?tagged=funny"><div class="_22yr2"><div class="_jjzlb"><img alt="#love #like #happy #smile #tbt #throwback #tagsforlike #men #menfashion #fashion #boy #handsome #sunglasses #funny #cute #goodevening #throwbackthursday #fitmen #fitness" class="_icyx7" id="pImage_443" src="https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/19985143_1944726462469632_2655387475194675200_n.jpg"></div><!-- react-empty: 7553 --><div class="_ovg3g"></div></div></a></div><div class="_8mlbc _vbtk2 _t5r8b"><a href="/p/BWfOl6SlDZF/?tagged=funny"><div class="_22yr2"><div class="_jjzlb"><img alt="•F A S T • F O O D • **Sprinting away the sprinkles** #quilledesigns #quilling #quilled #paperquilling #quilledpaper #paper #paperart #papercraft #paperartist #quillingstrips #comicstrip #comics #puns #playonwords #donuts #sprinkles #fastfood #funny #donut #sprinting" class="_icyx7" id="pImage_444" src="https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/20065944_151087882114276_504967203435577344_n.jpg"></div><!-- react-empty: 7562 --><div class="_ovg3g"></div></div></a></div><div class="_8mlbc _vbtk2 _t5r8b"><a href="/p/BWfOlxWg5ny/?tagged=funny"><div class="_22yr2"><div class="_jjzlb"><img alt="Lmao, this is not what i expected at all... hahahaha, I'll try again soon :(
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
#animation #traditionalanimation #animatic #art #drawing #draw  #pencil  #motion #character #alien #kawaii #cute #stopmotion #disney #cute #funny #frame #animacion #tradicional #design #diseño #dibujo #drawings #drawing" class="_icyx7" id="pImage_445" src="https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e15/c120.0.480.480/19955301_150281645530681_7822799075828301824_n.jpg"></div><!-- react-empty: 7571 --><div class="_ovg3g"></div></div><div class="_qihym"><div class="_cxj4a"><span class="_btsl3 _soakw coreSpriteVideoIconLarge">Video</span></div></div></a></div></div><div class="_myci9"><div class="_8mlbc _vbtk2 _t5r8b"><a href="/p/BWfOlrNjXI8/?tagged=funny"><div class="_22yr2"><div class="_jjzlb"><img alt="#shake #shakeit #shakeshack #shakeology #shakespeareinthepark #shaker#shakeitup #shakethatass #shakespeare #shakespearelives #shakespearesglobe #shakeologyaddict #funny#lol#lmao#date #indian #dubai #usa #ufc #boxing#muaythai" class="_icyx7" id="pImage_446" src="https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/20065225_333634613734880_2244990821642272768_n.jpg"></div><!-- react-empty: 7584 --><div class="_ovg3g"></div></div></a></div><div class="_8mlbc _vbtk2 _t5r8b"><a href="/p/BWfOlqJguA_/?tagged=funny"><div class="_22yr2"><div class="_jjzlb"><img alt="I'm Lego Batman 
#lego #batman #funny #keychain" class="_icyx7" id="pImage_447" src="https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/19933458_702485879950599_7655346332546105344_n.jpg"></div><!-- react-empty: 7593 --><div class="_ovg3g"></div></div></a></div><div class="_8mlbc _vbtk2 _t5r8b"><a href="/p/BWfOlp8nI8G/?tagged=funny"><div class="_22yr2"><div class="_jjzlb"><img alt="Love you❤️❤️#friend #friends #fun #TagsForLikes #funny #love #instagood #igers #friendship #party #chill #happy #cute #photooftheday #live #forever #smile #bff #bf #gf #best #bestfriend #lovethem #bestfriends #goodfriends #besties #awesome #memories #goodtimes #goodtime" class="_icyx7" id="pImage_448" src="https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/c135.0.810.810/19984263_412312419162449_1340519160630738944_n.jpg"></div><!-- react-empty: 7602 --><div class="_ovg3g"></div></div></a></div></div><div class="_myci9"><div class="_8mlbc _vbtk2 _t5r8b"><a href="/p/BWfOlpUA8Ac/?tagged=funny"><div class="_22yr2"><div class="_jjzlb"><img alt="#memes #memestagram #instafunny #funny #dankmeme" class="_icyx7" id="pImage_449" src="https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/19986053_1395318580545213_5434597534683103232_n.jpg"></div><!-- react-empty: 7612 --><div class="_ovg3g"></div></div></a></div><div class="_8mlbc _vbtk2 _t5r8b"><a href="/p/BWfOlaWl1yC/?tagged=funny"><div class="_22yr2"><div class="_jjzlb"><img alt="@danielle1of3 likes to joke that with all the money I spend @starbucks that we could be getting married at the Ritz, well now after getting my morning ice tea without my name and just my face drawn on my cup, I'm inclined to agree with her...#starbucks #barista #icetea #nycphotographer #nycphotography #nyc #brooklyn #facemask #art #drawing #draw #drawingoftheday #foodporn #foodies #foodlover #foodpic #foodstagram #fun #funny #refillplease #beard #model" class="_icyx7" id="pImage_450" src="https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/20065802_1529194863806276_2312596664898027520_n.jpg"></div><!-- react-empty: 7621 --><div class="_ovg3g"></div></div></a></div><div class="_8mlbc _vbtk2 _t5r8b"><a href="/p/BWfOlGFFbUh/?tagged=funny"><div class="_22yr2"><div class="_jjzlb"><img alt="#beach #street #shore #sky #beauty
#Repost#amazing #tbt #instagraff #nature #funny #pretty #c4c #l4l #night #noir #Love #vew #green #tree #art #all #pics #photofy#hdr" class="_icyx7" id="pImage_451" src="https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/c0.135.1080.1080/19986201_326503507806798_6900092237808402432_n.jpg"></div><!-- react-empty: 7630 --><div class="_ovg3g"></div></div></a></div></div><div class="_myci9"><div class="_8mlbc _vbtk2 _t5r8b"><a href="/p/BWfOlBmBvy_/?tagged=funny"><div class="_22yr2"><div class="_jjzlb"><img alt="mEeeeeEe" class="_icyx7" id="pImage_452" src="https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/19986090_1425807950830882_8070492657287168000_n.jpg"></div><!-- react-empty: 7640 --><div class="_ovg3g"></div></div></a></div><div class="_8mlbc _vbtk2 _t5r8b"><a href="/p/BWfOkyrgCZa/?tagged=funny"><div class="_22yr2"><div class="_jjzlb"><img alt="#spoof #funny #crazy #humour #jokes #vine #comedy" class="_icyx7" id="pImage_453" src="https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e15/c80.0.480.480/19985991_107038813218184_2045495655236894720_n.jpg"></div><!-- react-empty: 7649 --><div class="_ovg3g"></div></div><div class="_qihym"><div class="_cxj4a"><span class="_btsl3 _soakw coreSpriteVideoIconLarge">Video</span></div></div></a></div><div class="_8mlbc _vbtk2 _t5r8b"><a href="/p/BWfOkjlgdSz/?tagged=funny"><div class="_22yr2"><div class="_jjzlb"><img alt="Every minute should be enjoyed and savored.

#fun #instagramers #socialenvy #shopstemdesigns&nbsp; #smile #pretty #followme #nature #lol #fishing #hair #sunset #swag #throwbackthursday #instagood #beach #friends #hot #funny #blue #life #art #photo #cool #ebookwormsclub #bestoftheday #clouds #chasinglight #love #me" class="_icyx7" id="pImage_454" src="https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/c236.0.608.608/19955382_1493628214028033_4371753069210238976_n.jpg"></div><!-- react-empty: 7661 --><div class="_ovg3g"></div></div></a></div></div></div><div class="_ikcuh"><div class="_4tedc"><iframe aria-hidden="true" class="_823eg" tabindex="-1"></iframe></div></div><a href="/explore/tags/funny/?max_id=1558028080856028339" class="_8imhp _glz1g">Load more</a></div></article></main><nav class="_onabe _5z3y6" role="navigation"><div class="_giw59"></div><div class="_fjpuc _sq03j"><div class="_6v8vp _erzi3"><div class="_df358"><div class="_jha5b"><div class="_om391"><a class="_1b8in _soakw coreSpriteDesktopNavLogoAndWordmark" href="/">Instagram</a></div></div><div class="_9pxkq _icv3j"><input class="_9x5sw _qy55y" placeholder="Search" value="" type="text"><div class="_t1y9a _98hun"><div class="_etslc _1rn91"><span class="_oqxv9 coreSpriteSearchIcon"></span><span class="_9ea4j">Search</span></div></div></div><div class="_nhei4"><div class="_pq5am"><div class="_7smet"><a class="_soakw _vbtk2 coreSpriteDesktopNavExplore" href="/explore/">Find People</a></div><div class="_7smet"><a href="#" class="_im3et _vbtk2 coreSpriteDesktopNavActivity"><span class="_soakw">Activity Feed</span></a></div><div class="_7smet"><a class="_soakw _vbtk2 coreSpriteDesktopNavProfile" href="/memeyouhard/">Profile</a></div></div></div></div></div></div></nav><footer class="_oofbn" role="contentinfo"><div class="_mhrsk _pcuq6" style="max-width: 935px;"><nav class="_p1gbi" role="navigation"><ul class="_fh0f2"><li class="_fw3ds"><a class="_c4mil" href="/about/us/">About us</a></li><li class="_fw3ds"><a class="_c4mil" href="https://help.instagram.com/">Support</a></li><li class="_fw3ds"><a class="_c4mil" href="http://blog.instagram.com/">Blog</a></li><li class="_fw3ds"><a class="_c4mil" href="https://instagram-press.com/">Press</a></li><li class="_fw3ds"><a class="_c4mil" href="/developer/">API</a></li><li class="_fw3ds"><a class="_c4mil" href="/about/jobs/">Jobs</a></li><li class="_fw3ds"><a class="_c4mil" href="/legal/privacy/">Privacy</a></li><li class="_fw3ds"><a class="_c4mil" href="/legal/terms/">Terms</a></li><li class="_fw3ds"><a class="_c4mil" href="/explore/locations/">Directory</a></li><li class="_fw3ds"><span class="_17z9g _c4mil"><!-- react-text: 7716 -->Language<!-- /react-text --><select class="_nif11"><option value="af">Afrikaans</option><option value="cs">Čeština</option><option value="da">Dansk</option><option value="de">Deutsch</option><option value="el">Ελληνικά</option><option value="en">English</option><option value="es">Español</option><option value="fi">Suomi</option><option value="fr">Français</option><option value="id">Bahasa Indonesia</option><option value="it">Italiano</option><option value="ja">日本語</option><option value="ko">한국어</option><option value="ms">Bahasa Melayu</option><option value="nb">Norsk</option><option value="nl">Nederlands</option><option value="pl">Polski</option><option value="pt-br">Português (Brasil)</option><option value="pt">Português (Portugal)</option><option value="ru">Русский</option><option value="sv">Svenska</option><option value="th">ภาษาไทย</option><option value="tl">Filipino</option><option value="tr">Türkçe</option><option value="zh-cn">中文(简体)</option><option value="zh-tw">中文(台灣)</option><option value="bn">বাংলা</option><option value="gu">ગુજરાતી</option><option value="hi">हिन्दी</option><option value="hr">Hrvatski</option><option value="hu">Magyar</option><option value="kn">ಕನ್ನಡ</option><option value="ml">മലയാളം</option><option value="mr">मराठी</option><option value="ne">नेपाली</option><option value="pa">ਪੰਜਾਬੀ</option><option value="si">සිංහල</option><option value="sk">Slovenčina</option><option value="ta">தமிழ்</option><option value="te">తెలుగు</option><option value="ur">اردو</option><option value="vi">Tiếng Việt</option><option value="zh-hk">中文(香港)</option><option value="bg">Български</option><option value="fr-ca">Français (Canada)</option><option value="ro">Română</option><option value="sr">Српски</option><option value="uk">Українська</option></select></span></li></ul></nav><span class="_es4h6">© 2017 Instagram</span></div></footer><!-- react-empty: 7767 --><div class="_s1xpw _44kmz"><div class="_plwoo"></div></div></section>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML you are using too?

Comment: just posted it..

Comment: An actual text extract would have been nice. Screenshots of code (or HTML) are frowned upon. Imagine someone knows a good answer and want to help, but cannot quickly copy-paste your extract to test that their solution would work for you. They won't bother, and you won't have an answer.

Comment: I suspect it might not be picking the second one up as a sibling as there it a div layer in the tree between them. Try bringing your <a> elements out of the divs, just to see if that works at least.

Comment: well im trying to automate some jobs on a website(not mine), like clicks etc. so i don't have a chance to change the codes. Btw it is not possible to copy the HTML because the source contains a JSON file.

Comment: In your *html image*, what element are you trying to access? The *url*-stuff of your **xpath** probably matches those two *a*-elements. From there you then search for the **following sibling** that is also an *a*-element? There are no such elements in your *html*, the sibling of the first *a*-element is the last *div*-element at the bottom, so what are you trying to achieve? Also see the illustration here http://zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/Output_ger/example15.html

Comment: I'm trying to get the next <a href="" value so it is an url that is coming back. I can get it through  this "mainelem.findElement(By.xpath("//a[starts-with(@href, '/p/')]"));" but I can't get the next value. It is directly lying under the <div class="_8mlbc _vbtk2 _t5r8b">

Comment: I still can't do anything. logically it must be this: /following-sibling::span/section/main/article/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[@class='_8mlbc _vbtk2 _t5r8b'] so it takes all the <a elements after the div class "_8mlbc _vbtk2 _t5r8b" but it doesn't work..

Comment: Can you copy and paste the HTML so it's easier for us to help you?

Comment: Anyone who can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't edit the HTML then you can't use the `following-sibling` mechanism here. The fact is that each `<a>` link doesn't have any siblings - they are single children to `<div>` parents. I also notice that each parent is contained within the previous parent `<div>` too, resulting in a nested set of links.

I think your best option is to use the `WebElement.findElements()` method instead, to look for a List of `<a>` elements and loop through the results for processing. *Note: I've also added a `'.'` char at the start of your xpath, to search only the within the context of the `mainelem` result.*

```
WebElement mainelem = url.findElement(By.tagName("main"));
List<WebElement> piclinks = mainelem.findElements(By.xpath(".//a[starts-with(@href, '/p/')]"));

for (WebElement picLink : piclinks) {
    //... picLink processing...
}
```